# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException при написании тестов на Spring

Tags: java, spring, junit

Error creating bean with name 'ru. ... .test.UserServiceTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ru.sk.ips.services.UserServices' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ru. ... .test.UserServiceTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ru.sk.ips.services.UserServices' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Класс UserServiceTest

```
package ru. ... .test;
...

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    UserServices userService;

    @Test
    public void simpleTest {
      ... 
    }

}
```

Класс UserService

```
package ru. ... .services;

...

@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServices {

    @Autowired
    private DSLContext dsl;
    ...
}
```

Как таковой конфигурации в проекте нет

```
package ru. ...;

...

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

Этого не достаточно, чтобы поднять контекст во время теста.

Вам нужно указать конфиг класс для теста, используя @ContextConfiguration, либо использовать аннотацию @SpringBootTest.

Comment: @ContextConfiguration - конфигурации как таковой нет

Comment: @SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class) - если использовать, то при запуске тестов класс Application не находит